# Publish Message to Pub/Sub Topic With Schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi all i had a topic with schema that used for bigquery subscription
my topic schema is like this

```
resource "google_pubsub_schema" "my_schema_name" {
  name       = "my_schema_name"
  type       = "PROTOCOL_BUFFER"
  definition = <<EOF
syntax = "proto2";
message ProtocolBuffer {
  required string id = 1;
  required int64 profile_id = 2;
  optional string address = 3;
  required string date = 5;
}
EOF
}
```

and my BQ table

```
id | String | required
profile_id | Integer | required
address | String | nullable
date | Date | required
```

i have been successfully publish message to the topic and the subscription automatically insert it to the table using google pub/sub library
but i have a case where i need to publish it via https

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-topic:publish' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer myAccessToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "messages": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "id": "ID123",
                "profile_id": 123,
                "address": "somewhere in the world",
                "date": "2023-07-20",
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

with curl above i got this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"intValue\" at 'messages[0].attributes[2].value': Cannot find field.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
                "fieldViolations": [
                    {
                        "field": "messages[0].attributes[2].value",
                        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"intValue\" at 'messages[0].attributes[2].value': Cannot find field."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

if i quote the profile id

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-topic:publish' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer myAccessToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "messages": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "id": "ID123",
                "profile_id": "123",
                "address": "somewhere in the world",
                "date": "2023-07-20",
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

i got this error instead

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid data in message: Message failed schema validation.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "INVALID_JSON_PROTO_MESSAGE",
                "domain": "pubsub.googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "message": "Message failed schema validation",
                    "revisionInfo": "Could not validate message with any schema revision for schema: projects/88888888/schemas/my-topic-schema, last checked revision: revision_id=xxxxx failed with status: Invalid data in message: Could not parse JSON message."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the schema can be changed to avro or proto3 or anything if it can solve the issue (but must fulfill the BQ table criteria)

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are send a message that only puts fields in the attributes of the Pub/Sub message rather than sending the `data` portion of the message as JSON. A schema is not used to validate the attributes; it validates the `data` field. You would also need to base64-encode the data portion.

So if you want to send the JSON object

```
{
  "id": "ID123",
  "profile_id": "123",
  "address": "somewhere in the world",
  "date": "2023-07-20",
}
```

you would need to send the `curl` command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-topic:publish' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer myAccessToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "messages": [
        {
            "data": "ewogICJpZCI6ICJJRDEyMyIsCiAgInByb2ZpbGVfaWQiOiAiMTIzIiwKICAiYWRkcmVzcyI6ICJzb21ld2hlcmUgaW4gdGhlIHdvcmxkIiwKICAiZGF0ZSI6ICIyMDIzLTA3LTIwIiwKfQ=="
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: i see, your curl works, but is there any other option? because for my case i can't encode it to base64 programmatically.

Comment: No there is no other option. If using the REST API directly, the message data must be base64-encoded as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#message_format).